# ClickListener for Slide Menu items

Tags: android, menuitem, onclicklistener, slidingmenu

I defined a layout view in a .xml file called profile_sliding_menu.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#b5b5b5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pMenuProfileInformation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_profile_information"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/pMenuProfileInformation"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    ..........

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm creating the SlidingMenu from code:

```java
SlidingMenu menu;
menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.profile_sliding_menu);
```

It shows perfectly the menu, but i want to do some actions when the user chooses an option from the menu.
How can i access that buttons and assign them a event?

Thanks!

Comment: I make something like this, and all work:

 findViewById(R.id.pMenuProfileInformation).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "blablabal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   });

Comment: Please add this as an answer and accept it yourself. so that the others can reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I make something like this, and all work fine:

```java
findViewById(R.id.pMenuProfileInformation).setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "blablabal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The jfeinstein slidingmenu example uses SampleListFragment Adapter that extends ListFragment

ListFragment has an overriding method "onListItemClick()" that can be used for implementing slidemenu item click actions based on the menu position

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```